# How to design unconventional woocommerce shop?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

First a line about me: I have skills in html & css but no skills in php. I am new to wordpress, but I learned already to build a wordpress theme for my own from scratch. If I had a problem, I always found a solution on the internet. Now I have a problem and after searching for hours, I haven’t found any helpful tips.

I want to make a website with a little webshop inside, only one product for now. I did choose WooCommerce because it is popular and i thought maybe it works like wordpress. Now I have the problem that I have no idea how to design my site. I am sitting in front of countless files with code i do not understand. I want something similar to thie website below. Right half with an image and left half with product title, description and “add to cart” button. No category, no filters, no shop overview. Just a front page with one product.

Is it possible to do the same like designing a wordpress theme like `<h2><insert title code></h2>` then `<p><insert product description code></p>` or does WooCommerce works completely different? All tutorials I found were not helpful for me.

http://ilyaskin.com/mono/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Your question right now is very broad, while Stackoverflow focuses on **specific** questions about an issue with existing piece of code. If you have code you have written and tried out, please add this to your question, and focus the question to a **particular** problem with the code.

Comment: Hi! I think you can try a simpler tool, not Wordpress and WooCommerce. Have you tried the "Add to cart" stripe button ? https://www.powr.io/plugins/stripe-button/standalone?id=21957094& We have it implemented on : https://www.iproject.cat/mantenimiento-wordpress/

Comment: @squareskittles oh yea you are right. sorry for that but I can't offer any code because I haven't figured out how to start.

Comment: @gtamborero oh this looks cool! but I need various shipping costs and this plugin only offers a single one.

Answer (score -2):

There is a lot of question here then I will answer to one of these and I think it's better to create a new discussion for each other question.

If you to have only a product, you can start to put a shortcode to display the product details with button "add to cart" :
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-12

The next step is to customise the display and for that, the first question is to know if the theme can be updated. If yes, you have to start with a child theme :
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/